# NTP Clock on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, child-process, raspberry-pi

I've been tinkering around with making a fancy clock on a Raspberry Pi B. This little application will sync the Pi's time with an NTP server, then display it using `toilet` so it's nice n' big & centered on a monitor. This was made for a GUI-less Pi, and I'm looking to hopefully make it more efficient. Right now the seconds aren't a uniform duration (the `time.sleep(0.3)` is there to even it out), and I'm sure it's because the Pi is struggling to keep up with my newbie code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import sys
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime
import ntplib

NTP_MISS = 0

def display_clock():
    #Clock Positioning
    rows, columns = os.popen('stty size', 'r').read().split()
    h_pos = int(int(columns) / 6)
    v_pos = "\033[" + str(int(int(rows) / 6)) + ";0H"

    #Initialization
    check_ntp_time = time.time()
    os.system('setterm --cursor off -powersave off')
    subprocess.call("clear")

    #Meat & Potatoes
    try:
        while check_ntp_time + 86400 >= time.time():
            current_date = subprocess.check_output(["date", "+%r"]).strip().decode("utf-8")
            current_date = " " * h_pos + current_date
            sys.stdout.write(v_pos + subprocess.check_output(["toilet", "-w 200", current_date]).decode("utf-8"))
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(0.3)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Closing NTP Clock")
        os.system('setterm --cursor on -powersave on')
        subprocess.call("clear")
        print("Closed NTP Clock")
        exit()

    #Update time using NTP pool.
    get_ntp_time()



def get_ntp_time():
    call = ntplib.NTPClient()
    while True:
        try:
            #Try to connect to the NTP pool...
            response = call.request('pool.ntp.org')
            print("Time updated!")
            break
        except:
            NTP_MISS += 1
            if NTP_MISS >= 5:
                print("NTP server unavailable for too long! Terminating...")
                os.system('setterm --cursor on -powersave on')
                subprocess.call("clear")
                print("NTP Clock failed. Server unresponsive for too long.")
                exit()
            #Not a huge deal if we miss it, just continue displaying the clock.
            print("Could not connect to pool.")
            display_clock()
    #If we get a response, update the system time.
    t = datetime.fromtimestamp(response.tx_time)
    t = t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %Z')
    set_string = "--set=" + t
    subprocess.call(["date", set_string])
    display_clock()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    display_clock()
```

I'd prefer to use the `subprocess` instead of `os.system`, but for some reason using `subprocess` with `setterm` returned a "command not found" error. So that's why I'm using `os.system` instead.

What all can I do to optimize & clean up this code?

Answer (score 6):

In general your script looks good when considering the style and structure, but there are a few issues:

- *Strange name for `check_ntp_time`* – This holds the time since the last time you did `time.time()`, and in reality is a temporary variable for when you need to check it the last time. It doesn't convey the real purpose of the variable.

  I would rather do `time_to_check_ntp = time.time() + 86400`, and let the condition be `time.time() < time_to_check_ntp` or similar, which reads easier as to whether we've come to that time already, or not.
- *Consider replacing `toilet` with python stuff* – One option could be to use [pyfiglet](https://github.com/pwaller/pyfiglet), and another could be to use fonts of your own based on script suggestions from ["Is there a python library that allows to easily print ascii-art text?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632995/is-there-a-python-library-that-allows-to-easily-print-ascii-art-text) and ["ASCII Art With Letters"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26331644/1548472).
- *New function for setterm & clear* – Introduce a new function where you can set it to on or off, which would remove some repetition of code.
- *Replace call to `date` to get date with `datetime` module* – In general I would like for python script to do most of it using python stuff. Some of it like `clear` and `setterm`, or setting the date needs to be done in the shell on the terminal, so some can't be avoided, but stuff like getting the date I think should be done using internal tools, if possible.
- *Avoid the recursivity* – Both `display_clock()` and `get_ntp_time()` calls each other causing a bad recursivity. If you change `display_clock` to have a `while True:` loop you could have a `if time.time() > time_to_check_ntp:` which then calls `get_ntp_time()` which possibly should be named `correct_time_using_ntp()`, and sets a new `time_to_check_ntp`.
- *Remove output before clearing the terminal* – No point in outputting text straight ahead of a terminal clear. Nobody would be able to catch these message, unless something fails. I would remove it, or add a logger to keep track of the history of the script.

I'm not going to propose new code, as I don't have the ability to test it, but I hope my suggestions are meaningful and you see how to implement it. If not, please do comment.

Answer (score 5):

To even out the updates, you should just sleep for the remainder of the second.

Replace

```
time.sleep(0.3)
```

with

```
time.sleep(1 - time.time() % 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using a `while` loop but just using it to count up to 5. Instead, use a `for` loop where you count up to 5. In Python `for` loops can have an `else` block that gets called if the `for` loop never reaches a `break` statement. This means you can rearrange your code to look like this:

```
for _ in range(5):
    try:
        #Try to connect to the NTP pool...
        response = call.request('pool.ntp.org')
        print("Time updated!")
        break
    except:
        #Not a huge deal if we miss it, just continue displaying the clock.
        print("Could not connect to pool.")
        display_clock()
else:
    print("NTP server unavailable for too long! Terminating...")
    os.system('setterm --cursor on -powersave on')
    subprocess.call("clear")
    print("NTP Clock failed. Server unresponsive for too long.")
    exit()
```

This makes it easier to read, as the code to handle no `break` is put at the end, *after* the whole loop. Instead of splitting up the loop with the final case handled in the middle.

---

On further inspection, I see that you're intending to not loop 5 times on each function call, but only run this attempt 5 times in total. Your current code wont actually do that, it would raise an error. Running this code will demonstrate it:

```
var = 0

def function():
    var += 1

function()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 6, in <module>
  File "python", line 4, in function
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'var' referenced before assignment
```

`var` exists inside the global scope. This does mean that it could be read by `function`, eg. with `print(var)`. But if you try to modify this value, that violates the scope. This is also an issue with your `NTP_MISS` value.

To get around this, you'd either need to explicitly refer to it in the global scope with `global NTP_MISS` inside your function, or you'd have to pass it as a parameter to the function. Given that it would have to pass through another function, I would advocate for `global` in this case.

```
def get_ntp_time():
    global NTP_MISS
```

Now you could update your value as you have above without raising errors. If you want to keep a running total of the exceptions caught, then I recommend sticking with `while` and only using `for` if you decide to only break when there have been 5 exceptions in a row.

Comment: Hm. Well, my inner noob is showing: at what point does the `_` throwaway variable increment in this loop? During the `except`? Once it jumps out of the loop? Wouldn't it reset after it jumps out & gets called again?

Comment: @zomgdavidbowie I didn't realise before that it was meant to be a continuously updated number. In it's current state it would actually raise an error. I'll update my answer to explain.